# How do interpret this result for t-SNE plot results?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, tsne

I am trying to interpret this plot I created for a malware dataset. The dataset contains Benign and Malware data. I am having a hard time understanding what it means. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: t-SNE is very sensitive to hyperparameters, and reading it is a lot like reading tea leaves.

Comment: Is there any blue behind that orange circle on the right? It might help to plot the smaller points and/or color transparency (something like alpha=0.25, if you use matplotlib).